# Running Multiple Web Applciations on the Same LAN Server nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm serving 2 docker containers on a LAN network, a cloud server on port 5234 and a flask application other on 8080.

I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy to run them both on the same ip with different extensions. My config:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name 192.168.1.23;

location /web {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/flaskapp.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/flaskapp.error.log;
}

location /cloud {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5234;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.error.log;
}

}
```

but I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway when accessing 192.168.1.23/web or 192.168.1.23/cloud.

In flaskapp.error.log:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.72, server: 192.168.1.23, request: "GET /web HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "192.168.1.23"
```

In nextcloud.error.log:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.72, server: 192.168.1.23, request: "GET /cloud HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5234/cloud", host: "192.168.1.23"
```

Is there a way to run multiple web applications on the same ip like this or using different ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP Address. Try 127.0.0.1 which refers to the local host.
like this:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

Comment: Changed it, but I still get an 502 error trying to connect

Comment: Can you access http://192.168.1.23:8080 & http://192.168.1.23:5234 ?

Comment: Remove the trailing / like this: proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

Comment: Added some more info on the access error. Also, I tried removing the trailling / but still not working. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Add a trailing slash to the location. Location /web/ and Location /cloud/ because it is sending the path upstream